# What happens when I convert a empty string to LocalDateTime in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a code like below:

```
val logoutDt = history?.getBody() as? LocalDateTime
```

What is the value of `logoutDt` if `history?.getBody()`'s value is an empty string?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: First of all, have you tried it? Second, if `getBody()` returns `String`, the result will be `null`, as `String` cannot be casted to `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is `null`, you'll get a `TypeCastException` with `as` and simply `null` with `as?`:

> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.time.LocalDate

If it is an "empty string", you'll get `ClassCastException`:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate

Casts do no work that way.

You need to use slightly more code:

```
fun main() {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
    val date = LocalDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30", formatter)

    println(date) // 2011-12-03T10:15:30
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the question mark in `as?`. The value of `logoudDt` is `null` in both cases because `as?` is a "safe" cast

Comment: @user2340612, indeed, thanks. I've edited my answer. However, it doesn't result in `LocalDateTime` either.

Answer (score 0):

No matter whether the string is empty or has some content, *casting* it with `as?` to `LocalDateTime` will always produce `null`, and casting it with `as` will always result in a `ClassCastException`.

If you want to get a `LocalDateTime` from a `String` you have to *convert* it. You can do it with the `LocalDateTime.parse` static function:

```
val date: LocalDateTime? = history?.getBody()?.let { body -> LocalDateTime.parse(body) }
```